# Python, extract date from XML

Tags: python, xml, date, extract

Apologies, my Python knowledge is pretty non-existant. I need to extract a date from some XML which is in a format similar to:

```
<Header>
<Version>1.0</Version>
....
    <cd:Data>...</Data>
    .....
    <cd:DateReceived>20070620171524</cd:DateReceived>
```

From looking around here I found something similar

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from xml.dom.minidom import parse  
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("date.xml")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement

print collection.getElementsByTagName("cd:DateReceived").item(0)
```

However this only prints the Hex value:

```
<DOM Element: cd:DateReceived at 0x1529e0>
```

How can I get the date 20070620171524?

I've tried using the following

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from xml.dom.minidom import parse  
import xml.dom.minidom

# Open XML document using minidom parser
DOMTree = xml.dom.minidom.parse("date.xml")
collection = DOMTree.documentElement

date = cd:DateReceived[0].firstChild.nodeValue
print date
```

but it gives an error as it doesn't like the "cd" part of the tag

```
date = cd:DateReceived[0].firstChild.nodeValue
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: that hex value is the address of the pointer to a DOM element object. If you do a `.data` on it should return the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection.getElementsByTagName("cd:DateReceived").item(0)` returns a node. from that node, you can get `nodeValue`